# Custom enum base class for flags

Tags: c#, oop, .net-core

I'm making a custom enumeration class along the lines of the [Microsoft recommendation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/microservice-ddd-cqrs-patterns/enumeration-classes-over-enum-types) but struggling to make a version that supports flag-style enums.

The problem occurs when trying to bitwise or together two instances to create a new instance that doesn't exist.

```cs
public abstract class Enumeration<TEnum>
    where TEnum : Enumeration<TEnum>
{
    public int Id { get; private set; }
    public string Name { get; private set; }

    protected Enumeration(int id, string name) => (Id, Name) = (id, name);

    public override string ToString() => Name;

    public static IEnumerable<TEnum> GetAll() =>
        typeof(T).GetFields(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly)
                 .Where(info => enumerationType.IsAssignableFrom(info.FieldType))
                 .Select(f => f.GetValue(null))
                 .Cast<T>();

    public static Enumeration<TEnum> operator |(Enumeration<TEnum> left, Enumeration<TEnum> right)
    {
        // This is the problem method!
        // I can obviously bitwise or together the two values, but how do I create an instance
        // of TEnum from here so that is has a valid name?

        // For instance, Colors.Red | Colors.Blue would need to be an instance where
        // Id == (1 << 0 | 1 << 1) and Name == "Red, Blue".
    }

    // Other utility methods ...
}

public class Colors : Enumeration<Colors>
{
    public static readonly Colors Red = new Colors(1 << 0, "Red");
    public static readonly Colors Blue = new Colors(1 << 1, "Blue");
    public static readonly Colors Green = new Colors(1 << 2, "Green");

    public Colors(int id, string name) : base(id, name) { }
}
```

If this is an xy problem I'd be happy to listen to alternative ideas as well.

Comment: Have you tried `return new TEnumeration<TEnum>(left.Id | right.Id, $"{left.Name}, {right.Name}");`?

Comment: The problem is always going to be that you cannot construct `Colors` inside of `Enumeration`. (ie, the comment above will not work)

Comment: @Jamiec That's true, but OP could add a an implicit or explicit cast to `Colors` that accepted a `TEnumeration<Colors>`, I think?

Comment: That would mean an ex/implicit cast to _every_ type of enumeration from the base class. Yuck!

Comment: @Jamiec Is that any worse than adding the operator overload to each derived class as you suggested? :)

Comment: You can do it with reflection like so `return (Enumeration<TEnum>)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(TEnum), left.Id | right.Id, $"{left.Name}, {right.Name}");` but you'll still need to cast the result (i.e. Colors redBlue = (Colors)(Colors.Red | Colors.Blue);`).

Comment: @itsme86 worked out a way to not have to do that :) and no reflection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is going to always be that you cannot construct the instance of `Colors` from inside the abstract base class natively. ie, You can constrain a generic to have `new()` but not to have a *specific* constructor like `new(int, string)`.

So one option is to define (and redefine for each instance of your enumeration) the operator inside the concrete class itself

```
public class Colors : Enumeration<Colors>
{
    public static readonly Colors Red = new Colors(1 << 0, "Red");
    public static readonly Colors Blue = new Colors(1 << 1, "Blue");
    public static readonly Colors Green = new Colors(1 << 2, "Green");

    public Colors(int id, string name) : base(id, name) { }
    
    public static Colors operator |(Colors left, Colors right)
    {
        return new Colors(left.Id | right.Id, $"{left.Name}, {right.Name}");
    }
}
```

Live example of it working, but I suspect this isnt going to be what you want to do: https://dotnetfiddle.net/KBQEt4

Another option is give each enumeration the smarts to create itself (ie, getting round the lack of specific constructor constraint), then you *can* have the operator on the base class:

```
public abstract class Enumeration<TEnum>
    where TEnum : Enumeration<TEnum>
{
    public int Id { get; private set; }
    public string Name { get; private set; }
    

    protected Enumeration(int id, string name) => (Id, Name) = (id, name);

    public override string ToString() => Name;

    public static Enumeration<TEnum> operator |(Enumeration<TEnum> left, Enumeration<TEnum> right)
    {
        return left.Create(left.Id | right.Id, $"{left.Name}, {right.Name}");
    }
    
    protected abstract Enumeration<TEnum> Create(int id, string name);
    

    // Other utility methods ...
}

public class Colors : Enumeration<Colors>
{
    public static readonly Colors Red = new Colors(1 << 0, "Red");
    public static readonly Colors Blue = new Colors(1 << 1, "Blue");
    public static readonly Colors Green = new Colors(1 << 2, "Green");

    public Colors(int id, string name) : base(id, name) { }
    
    protected override Enumeration<Colors> Create(int id, string name) => new Colors(id,name);
    
}
```

Live example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/8ZBQqk

Comment: I appreciate the response! Unfortunately, this is the exact thing I was trying to avoid-I don't want everyone who makes an enumeration have to re-define a method. Although, I do like the second option where the child class has to define how to create an instance of itself. I'm not sure if that's better or worse than using Activator.

Comment: @Coda17 Oh I agree the first option is terrible, hence why I carried on thinking.

Comment: Seems like the only options are this or using Activator so marking this as accepted.